# how do you split a string to create nested list?

Tags: python, string, list, split

How would you split a string like

```
'1,55,6,89,2|7,29,44,5,8|767,822,999'
```

on the two delimiters `','` and `'|'` such that you have a list with the values like:

```
[[1, 55, 6, 89, 2], [7, 29, 44, 5, 8], [767, 822, 999]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

List comprehension are the most terse way to accomplish this.

```
>>> s = '1,55,6,89,2|7,29,44,5,8|767,822,999'
>>> [[int(x) for x in ss.split(',')] for ss in s.split('|')]
[[1, 55, 6, 89, 2], [7, 29, 44, 5, 8], [767, 822, 999]]
```

Comment: Ah, the classic "fastest gun in the west" reward on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data = [x.split(',') for x in input_string.split('|')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_data = [map(int, line.split(',')) for line in input_string.split('|')]
```

Comment: Please format your code, and think about whether `map` is really different enough from an inner list comprehension to merit an otherwise redundant answer.

Answer (score -3):

```
import re


regx = re.compile('(\A)|(\|)|(\Z)')

def repl(mat, di = {1:'[[', 2:'],[', 3:']]'} ):
    return di[mat.lastindex]

ss = '1,55,6,89,2|7,29,44,5,8|767,822,999'

my_data = eval( regx.sub(repl,ss) )

print my_data[1]
print my_data[1][2]
```

result

```
[7, 29, 44, 5, 8]
44
```

I know: some will scream to not use eval()

**Edit**

```
ss = '1,55,6,89,2|7,29,44,5,8|767,822,999' 
my_data = eval( ss.replace('|','],[').join(('[[',']]')))
```

Comment: Yes, we will scream not to use `eval`, especially since it is completely unnecessary.

Comment: That's not eval() which is unnecessary, it's regex. - By the way, I have an idea to not use eval() : ``exec( regx.sub(repl,ss) )`` with ``di = {1:'my_data = [[', 2:'],[', 3:']]'}`` ! pff pff pff