# how do you split lines of strings to create nested list?

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

how would you split these lines of strings in a text file and create a nested list or dictionary?:

```
Ali/22/Bankacı
Ahmet/28/Kasap
Mehmet/31/Bakkal
```

such that you have a list with the values like:

```
my_data['Ali'][1]= 'Bankacı'
```

Which is the most pythonic approach?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: So others can ask exactly this sort of question but I can't?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680729/how-do-you-split-a-string-to-create-nested-list

I'm just looking for the most pythonic way

Comment: `"asked 6 years, 3 months ago"`. If someone steals and didn't get caught that time, does it mean you can steal? All I'm asking is show your efforts and it would attract answers quicker and faster... It's not hard.

Comment: @MooingRawr Personally I don't mind quick questions like these :)

Comment: @JoeIddon that's fine you are free to answer what ever you want, my comments are align with what the site's guide lines are.

Comment: @MooingRawr Would you mind pointing me to those guidelines so I could have a read?

Comment: @JoeIddon That's basically what a [MCVE] is but if you wish you can dig around the meta posts such as : https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort or https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/210868 There are quite a bit of posts on this topic in Meta, search around. Oh and you can see what types of questions should be asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which this question currently doesn't fit...

Comment: @MooingRawr Thanks, those links were really informative.

Comment: @Soner Just a note: If you make a short Python program to solve this problem, and ask on Code Review whether it is Pythonic, that *might* meet their guidelines. (You can check their [FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour)). But give up on finding any *most* Pythonic way to do things. Past a certain point, it's simply up to personal taste, or design requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't answer a question with no attempt, but this can be done easily with a one-line `dictionary-comprehension`:

```
{l[:l.index('/')]:l.split('/')[1:] for l in open('f.txt').read().split('\n')[:-1]}
```

which then allows accessing in the format of:

```
>>> d['Mehmet'][1]
'Bakkal'
```

---

Or alternatively, you could create a `2d list` with another `comprehension`:

```
[l.split('/') for l in open('f.txt').read().split('\n')[:-1]]
```

which gives:

```
[['Ali', '22', 'Bankacı'], ['Ahmet', '28', 'Kasap'], ['Mehmet', '31', 'Bakkal']]
```

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be this one:

```
FILE = 'file.txt'

result = {}
with open(FILE, encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        line = line.strip().split('/')
        result[line[0]] = line[1:]

print(result['Ali'][1])
```

Or, nicely put within a function:

```
def data_to_dict(file_path):
    """
    Some docstring here which tells the user what the function does
    """

    result = {}
    with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
        for line in my_file:
            line = line.strip().split('/')
            result[line[0]] = line[1:]
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = data_to_dict('file.txt')
    print(d['Ali'][1])
```

What I'm doing above is:

- read a file line by line (from which I remove the `\n` at the end)
- for each line I create a list by splitting the string after `/` character (at this point, a line will look like this: `['Ali', '22', 'Bankacı']`)
- use the first element in the list as a key and the rest of the list as a value

**!** This won't get you the correct results if the first element in two(or more) lists will be the same (you'll always get the value for the last one)

---

If you also want to get rid of the duplicate keys issue, an alternative might look like this:

```
def data_to_dict(file_path):
    """
    Some docstring here which tells the user what the function does
    """

    result = {}
    with open(file_path, encoding='utf-8') as my_file:
        for i, line in enumerate(my_file):
            line = line.strip().split('/')
            key, val = line[0], line[1:]

            if key not in result:
                result[key] = val
            else:
                new_key = '{}_{}'.format(key, i)
                result[new_key] = val
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = data_to_dict('file.txt')
    print(d)
    print(d['Ali'][1])
```

For this file:

> ```
> Ali/22/Bankacı
> Ali/28/Kasap
> Mehmet/31/Bakkal
> ```

The output will look like this:

```
>> {'Ali': ['22', 'Bankacı'], 'Ali_1': ['28', 'Kasap'], 'Mehmet': ['31', 'Bakkal']}
>> Bankacı
```