# How can i use python's .split with 2 delimiters

Tags: python, list, split, delimiter

While trying to solve some python exercices I found myself needing to split a string using the .split with 2 delimiters but i cant make it work. I've searched in other people's questions but the answer is always to use the re.split which i cant use because these are exerceices for class in which i can't use it.

this is my code:

```
f1=open("data/namesStudents.txt")
f2=open("data/namesGrades.txt")
text=f1.read().split()
text2=f2.read().split("\n")
text2
```

To put this in context this is an exercice in which i have to get the grades of students off a txt file(they are like this basicly :14 15 14 17\n 14 14\n\n 13 10\n 13 10 11) and then make the average of the grades of each student and add it to the other txt file.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: that's the wrong dupe, they are not splitting on multiple delimiters and have worded their question wrong.

Comment: Hmm. Then I suppose I don't understand the question.

Comment: Can you use replace?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: they have lines, each line needs to be split on spaces.

Comment: In other words, they want to split by spaces and newlines? In that case the duplicate fits, doesn't it? Edit: I see what you're saying. They want a nested list as output, huh. I have to admit, I'm not sure how you arrived at that conclusion. Edit 2: Nvm, I can see it now. Makes sense.

Comment: @MartijnPieters How's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680729/how-do-you-split-a-string-to-create-nested-list) for a dupe?

Comment: @Aran-Fey: that'd answer the direct question on how to split multiple times, yes. This *is* an X-Y problem however.

Comment: Related/dupe: [How to read each line from a file into list word by word in Python](//stackoverflow.com/q/27722068)

Answer (score 2):

You want to split each *line* you have split out from the file. The first split produces a list of strings, then you need to call split again, on each of those strings:

```
values_per_line = [line.split() for line in f2.read().split('\n')]
```

Not that you actually need to split twice. You could just *loop directly over the file*:

```
values_per_line = [line.split() for line in f2]
```

Looping over a file gives you the lines in a file without having to call `.read()` and splitting.