# Create list from comma separated string

Tags: python

I want to create a list from a list of items, where some of the items include values separated by commas. In other words, from

`['a, b', 'c', 'd, e']`

achieve

`[['a', 'c', 'd'], ['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'd'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]`

I tried iterating over each item in nested loops, but the comma separation seems to be an issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try the split (',') method

Comment: Please update the question to show the code you've tried, it's output and *exactly* where you are stuck.

Comment: It's seems like you have to divide your problem to 2 steps (which both have answers here): 1) convert your list of strings to a nested list of letters ([how do you split a string to create nested list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680729/how-do-you-split-a-string-to-create-nested-list)) 2) Then get the combinations from this nested list ([All combinations of a list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798854/all-combinations-of-a-list-of-lists))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tackle the problem of the comma separation we can split each string in the list.

```
data = ['a, b', 'c', 'd, e']
print([value.split(',') for value in data])
```

This gives us `['a', ' b'], ['c'], ['d', ' e']]`

To get rid of those extra whitespaces we can modify the function by using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to apply [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to each resulting element of the inner list.

```
data = ['a, b', 'c', 'd, e']
print([list(map(str.strip, value.split(','))) for value in data])
```

The result is `[['a', 'b'], ['c'], ['d', 'e']]`

Now we can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for the final combinations.

```
import itertools
data = ['a, b', 'c', 'd, e']
data_normalized = [list(map(str.strip, value.split(','))) for value in data]
print(list(itertools.product(*data_normalized)))
```

The result is `[('a', 'c', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'e'), ('b', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'e')]`.

Comment: Was trying to work this one out myself - thanks for introducing `product`. Learned something new today!